# Delete parent div if child with class is present, without deleting other instances

Tags: jquery, html, web-frontend

I need to remove a div from the DOM if it has a child div with a specific class name, without removing the child div.

I tried using .remove() within an if/then statement, but when I do that it still removes all the instances of the targeted parent div, even those without the child.

The parent and child-type-B classes are automatically generated.

```
<div class="overall">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-A">
         // stuff that can't be deleted
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // even more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the entire parent div if the child has class child-type-A, so it looks like this:

```
<div class="overall">
   <div class="child-type-A">
      // stuff that can't be deleted
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // more stuff that can't be deleted
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // even more stuff that can't be deleted
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I thought would work, but it does not (it removes all parents and children if child-type-A is present).

```
if( '.parent > .child-type-A' ) {
 $( 'parent' ).remove();
}
```

I would expect that the div targeted by the 'if' would be the only affected div, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.child-type-A' ).closest('.parent').replaceWith($( '.child-type-A' ).closest('.parent').contents());
  //you can do this one also
   //$( '.child-type-A' ).parent('.parent').replaceWith($( '.child-type-A' ).parent('.parent').contents());
});
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.child-type-A' ).closest('.parent').replaceWith($( '.child-type-A' ).closest('.parent').contents());
  //you can do this one also
   //$( '.child-type-A' ).parent('.parent').replaceWith($( '.child-type-A' ).parent('.parent').contents());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overall">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-A">
         // stuff that can't be deleted
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // even more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

***In case more than one `child-type-A` div present inside `overall` div:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.parent').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('div').hasClass('child-type-A')){
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).contents());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overall">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-A">
         // stuff that can't be deleted
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-B">
         // even more stuff
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-type-A">
         // some other stuff
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LNML  in any case more than one `child-type-A` div can be presented inside `overall` div?

Comment: do you mean could more than one child-type-A occur inside overall? No, there will only be one.

Comment: @LNML  i have covered that condition also 
in my second working example snippet also.